# Constructor design for a class which delegates a value to one of its member variables

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, move-semantics, perfect-forwarding

Please consider the following `tree` class

```
template<typename T>
class tree
{
public:
    template<typename U>
    tree(U&& value)
        : m_value(std::forward<U>(value))
    { }

private:
    T m_value;
};
```

and some verbose class `foo` which is constructed by its `std::string name` which is printed via `std::cout` whenever one of its constructors is invoked.

```
foo a("a"), b("b");
foo const c("c");
tree<foo> s(std::move(a)), t(b), u(c);
```

yields the following output:

```
a constructed
b constructed
c constructed
a moved
b copied
c copied
```

which is as expected.

> How does this work?

To be specific: We cannot use

```
tree(T&& value)
    : m_value(std::forward<T>(value))
{ }
```

*Why*? Well, cause we force `decltype(value)` to be `foo&&` which is not the case in `t(b)` and `u(c)`. We would need to provide

```
tree(T const& value)
    : m_value(value)
{ }
```

as well, if we want to use this arguable variant. The ctor used in the `tree` implementation works cause of the [reference collapsing rules](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2002/n1377.htm#References%20to%20References).

> But why can't we use
>
> ```
> template<typename U>
> tree(U&& value)
>     : m_value(std::forward<T>(value))
> { }
> ```
>
> instead?

Well, the reason is that in `u(c)` we have `U = foo const& = decltype(value)`, but `std::forward<T>` only accepts `foo&` or `foo&&`, since `T = foo`. In contrast, `std::forward<U>` accepts `foo const&` (or `foo const&&`), since `U = foo const&`.

> So, if I'm not overlooking something, we should use `template<typename U> tree(U&&)` instead of a `tree(T const&)`, `tree(T&&)` combination. **But**: The compiler will take the `template<typename U> tree(U&&)` ctor in `push_back`, where the intend is that the move ctor of `tree` is taken:

```
foo a("a"), b("b");
foo const c("c");

tree<foo> t("root");
t.emplace_back(std::move(a));
t.emplace_back(b);
t.emplace_back(c);

tree<foo> u("other root");
u.push_back(t); // cannot convert argument 1 from 'tree<foo>' to 'std::string const&'
```

> What can I do? Do I need to use the `tree(T const&)`, `tree(T&&)` combination instead?

[Sorry for being a bit too verbose, but I felt responsible for clarifying any technical issue before asking for design.]

Answer (score 1):

A greedy constructor such as `template<typename U> tree(U&&)` must be suitably constrained, or you'll have a lot of problems down the road. You saw it hijack copy construction from a non-const lvalue because it's a better match than the copy constructor. It also defines an implicit conversion from everything under the sun, which can have "fun" effects on overload resolution.

A possible constraint might be "accept only things that are convertible to `T`":

```
template<typename U, class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<U, T>>>
tree(U&& u) : m_value(std::forward<U>(u)) {}
```

Or perhaps "accept only things that are convertible to `T` and not a `tree`".

```
template<class U>
using not_me = std::negation<std::is_same<U, tree>>;

template<typename U, 
         class = std::enable_if_t<std::conjunction_v<not_me<std::decay_t<U>>,
                                                     std::is_convertible<U, T>>>>
tree(U&& u) : m_value(std::forward<U>(u)) {}
```

Comment: Why is convertibility to `T` important?

Comment: @0xbadf00d So that you don't define implicit conversions that don't work.

Comment: But when they don't work, they generate a compiler error anyway. What am I missing?

Comment: @0xbadf00d Since the error doesn't happen until you enter the constructor body, overload resolution still thinks that there's an implicit conversion, so e.g., `void foo(tree<int>); void foo(tree<int*>); foo(nullptr);` is ambiguous. It also makes `is_convertible` and `is_constructible` produce wrong answers.

Comment: Ah, I see. Without the `enable_if` even `std::is_convertible<std::string, tree<int>>::value` would be `true`. So, I assume we should add `class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<U, T>>` as template parameter to the ctor and `emplace_back`.  Moreover, I assume we should add `class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<Tree>, tree>>` as template parameter to `push_back`.

Comment: But I don't understand why we should check for `!std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<U>, tree>>` in the ctor. If we got a `tree<int> t`, then `tree<int> u(t)` should call the copy ctor and `tree<int> v(std::move(t))` the move ctor and *not* the other ctor. Am I missing something?

Comment: @0xbadf00d That's for things like `tree<std::any>`.

Comment: I came to the conclusion that I don't need `emplace_back` and should use `template<typename U, class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<U, tree>>> void push_back(U&& value) { m_children.push_back(std::forward<U>(value)); }` instead. What do you think? Could you please explain why we need to check for `!std::is_same_v</* ... */>` for `tree<std::any>`? The problem is that `tree` is convertible to `std::any` and hence we wouldn't be able to call the copy/move ctor, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106854/discussion-between-t-c-and-0xbadf00d).

Answer (score 0):

You can do both.

If you go with:

```
template<typename U>
tree(U&& value)
    : m_value(std::forward<U>(value))
{ }
```

the downside is that any one-argument constructor of `T` can be invoked this way. This may not be what you want. For example, with that variant, the following is valid:

```
struct foo
{
    foo() = default;
    foo(const foo &ref) = default;
    explicit foo(int);
};

tree<foo> t(10);
t = 20;
```

This is a decision you need to find for yourself, however, I personally see that as a huge downside. I would make that constructor `explicit` (eliminating the second initialisation) and go for `tree(const T&)` along with  `tree(T&&)` to avoid the first initialisation.

Comment: We could declare `template<typename U> tree(U&&)` to be `explicit`. Then, `t = 20` wouldn't be possible.

Comment: @0xbadf00d That is what I wrote in my last paragraph, yes. Although probably not that clear.